# Adding controls to dynamics crm 2011 dynamically

Tags: forms, controls, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to keep a list of records with multiple fields, and enter them via one form, that shows the existing records as a list made of different text boxes. And a "new" button on the same form that'll create a new row of textboxes for the new entry.

Is it possible to create controls like textboxes dynamically on a form, as a result of button click? With JS or plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you are probably best making a custom web page and presenting it in an iFrame on your form.

I don't believe creating textboxes dynamically will work very well, I don't think it would be supported - you would have to change the DOM. Also you would have to implement some weird and overly complicated logic.

Answer (score 1):

I've been given requirements like this in the past. Although not totally supported, it is possible and I've seen it done many times.

Your best bet is to read up on some documentation to get familiar with making requests through javascript to the CRM service. You'll need to add libraries to your solution and make sure the form that is utilizing them references them.

Here's where to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx

jQuery and jQueryUI will also make your life a lot easier when making DOM changes with javascript.

Read up on knockoutjs. I've essentially done the same thing you're asking and utilizing knockout made the task of adding\removing\updating rows so much simpler.

The best way you can approach your task is to first create an html page web resource that has your basic structure. Also create a javascript web resource that the page references. This file will be what works to dynamically modifies the page. In your entity form, add a new side navigation link and point it at your web resource.

Now when that web page loads, have an event handler in the js file that requests the list of records for that entity and displays them. From here you can include event handlers and buttons that will allow you to capture events and then make the appropriate service calls to CRM.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the fields already on the form in a separate hidden tab?

Then use javascript to:
Show the tab
Show a submit button
(user inputs data)
Submit the values via ajax (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328025.aspx)
Clear the text boxes
Hide the tab